# Making a dictionary from files in which keys are filenames and values are strings with specific character

Tags: python, bioinformatics, fasta

so my problem is - I have proteomes in FASTA format, which look like this:

**Name of the example file:**

```
GCA_003547095.1_protein.faa
```

**Contents:**

```
>CAG77607.1
ABCDEF
>CAG72141.1
CSSDAS
```

And I also have files that contain just names of the proteins, i.e.:

**Filename:**

```
PF00001
```

**Contents:**

```
CAG77607.1
CAG72141.1
```

My task is to iterate through proteomes using list of proteins to find out how many proteins are in each proteome. PE told me that it should be a dictionary made from filenames of proteomes as keys and sequence names after ">" as values.

**My approach was as follows:**

```
import pandas as pd
file_names = open("proteomes_list").readlines()

d = {x: pd.read_csv("/proteomes/" + "GCA_003547095.1_protein.faa").columns.tolist() for x in file_names}
print (d)
```

As You can see I've made proteome filenames into list (using simple bash "ls", these are ONLY names of proteomes) and then creating dictionary with sequence names as values - unfortunetly each proteome (including the tested proteome) has only one value.
I will be grateful if You could shed some light on my case.

My goal was to make dictionary where key would be i.e. GCA_003547095.1_protein.faa and value i.e. CAG77607.1, CAG72141.1.

Comment: Unfortunately your question is not clear. Instead of using the word proteome, if you simply indicate what you are trying to do with each it would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the output you expect. This function should iterate over your file and grab the `fasta` file header or the name of the proteins that are expected in the file. Here is a quick function that can create a list of the `fasta` header.
You can create the dictionary you mentioned buy iterating over the file names and update the parent dictionary

```py
import os 
def extract_proteomes(folder: str, filename: str) -> list[str]:
    with open(os.path.join(folder, filename), mode='r') as file:
        content: str = file.read().split('\n')
    protein_names = [i[1:] for i in content if i.startswith('>')]
    if not protein_names:
        protein_names = [i for i in content if i]
    return protein_names

folder = "/Users/user/Downloads/"
files = ["GCA_003547095.1_protein.faa", "PF00001"]
d = {}
for i in files:
    d.update({i: extract_proteomes(folder=folder, filename=i)})
```

Comment: Hi, thank You some much for Your answer. Unfortnuetly, there seems to be some issue with defining a function, and its "TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable" at line 2 of Your code, I was not able to solve this.

Comment: Can you please clarify which version of python are you using? This code should work in python 3.8 and up. Not very sure if it will work with older versions. If you are using older version of python remove the [type-hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) from the code above and it should work.